# Defining allowed value ranges in type member in F#

Tags: f#, domain-driven-design

I'm playing around with [units of measure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/units-of-measure) in F# and I'm currently trying to create compound units of measure for length and mass to reflect colloquial speech in the imperial system, e.g. "I'm 5 foot 10" or "She weighs 8 stone and 11 pounds" in the US and the UK.

I've defined a module for standard (non-compound) units like so:

```ml
module Units
    // Mass
    [<Measure>] type kg // Kilogram
    [<Measure>] type g  // Gram
    [<Measure>] type lb // Pound (mass)
    [<Measure>] type st // Stone (mass)
    
    // Conversions
    ...

    // Length
    [<Measure>] type m      // Metre
    [<Measure>] type cm     // Centimetre
    [<Measure>] type inch   // Inch
    [<Measure>] type ft     // Foot

    // Conversions
    ...
```

And I've defined compound units in a different module:

```ml
module CompoundUnits
    open Units
    
    // Mass
    type StonesAndPounds = {
        Stones: float<st>
        Pounds: float<lb>
    }

    // Length
    type FeetAndInches = {
        Feet: float<ft>
        Inches: float<inch>
    }
```

However, with the way I've currently written the compound mass and length types, there's room for illegal states (such as negative values) and states that are *technically correct* but not preferred:

```ml
// 39 lbs = 2 st 11 lbs
let eightStoneEleven: StonesAndPounds = { Stones = 6.0<st>; Pounds = 39.0<lb> }
// 22" = 1' 10"
let fiveFootTen: FeetAndInches = { Feet = 4.0<ft>; Inches = 22.0<inch> }
```

In his book "Domain Modeling made Functional" Scott Wlaschin talks about making illegal states unrepresentable, so I was wondering if there was a way to enforce some kind of restriction on my compound types so that `0<ft> <= Feet`, `0<inch> <= Inches <= 12<inch>` and `0<st> <= Stones`, `0<lb> <= Pounds <= 14<lb>`.

Comment: I think you'd have to define the type as a class or struct rather than a record and provide custom setters with range checking.

Comment: https://draptik.github.io/posts/2020/02/10/fsharp-smart-constructor/ -> this sounds like a use case for a smart constructor (disclaimer: F# is not a language I have experience in) which, for the `StonesAndPounds` case would add pounds / 14 to stones and set pounds to pounds % 14.  Note that unlike in the article, these could be smart constructors which are total.

Comment: @LeviRamsey good point, I didn't even realize I could've used `int<st>` and `int<ft>`. I'll give that a read, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A common pattern is to create a module for the type, which contains its definition plus `create` functions and other validation logic.

Scott has some examples on his website, as part of his 'Designing with Types' series.

https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/designing-with-types-non-strings/

You can't enforce the restrictions on the units of measure themselves, but you could create dedicated types to represent your compound measurements as Scott does with `SafeDate` and `NonNegativeInt` etc.

These could still use the 'standard' units of measure for their component properties.

A quote from the article:

"Units of measure can indeed be used to avoid mixing up numeric values of different type, and are much more powerful than the single case unions we’ve been using.

On the other hand, units of measure are not encapsulated and cannot have constraints. Anyone can create a int with unit of measure  say, and there is no min or max value."

Comment: Thanks, that's a good link, but what bothers me is that this still is a runtime check that requires all related code to accommodate `None` values. Ideally (this might not be possible) I'd like to write these sorts of things in such a way that they get caught at compile time. E.g. `NonNegativeInt -5` -> does not compile.